# 80% при запуске spring boot проекта (gradle)

Tags: spring, gradle, spring-boot

После обновления версии gradle, spring boot plugin и еще пары зависимостей, проект начал запускаться и зависать на 80%, при этом сам проект работает. Читал на зарубежных форумах, что это нормально. Но меня это несколько не устраивает. Что можно сделать в данной ситуации?

gradle 4.10.3
spring boot plugin 1.5.19

Comment: Похоже ты его запускаешь как gradle task, если ты это делаешь в IDE, то разумеется IDE ничего не знает что там грейдл делает, она просто ждет окончания исполнения задания. В IDE лучше использовать встроенные механизмы запуска того же main метода, или какой нибудь jettyrun для запуска webapp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это нормально. Gradle считает, что сборка закончилась, когда процесс завершился. Твой процесс сборки никогда не завершается (потому что сервер, запущеный в процессе сборки продолжает бежать).
Да, запускать сервер из процесса сборки это немного misuse, но это удобно, практично, и работает :)